# How can I download an AWS open data set to my machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, opendata

I would like to use AWS CLI to download a publicly available data set to my machine, but as [the Registry of Open Data](https://registry.opendata.aws) only provides an *Amazon Resource Name* (ARN) and no URL, I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, for [Therapeutically Applicable Research to Generate Effective Treatments (TARGET)](https://registry.opendata.aws/target/) the arn is:

> arn:aws:s3:::gdc-target-phs000218-2-open

Thus, the **bucket name** is

> gdc-target-phs000218-2-open

To **list** it:

```
aws s3 ls s3://gdc-target-phs000218-2-open
```

To **copy** it to your local folder (large dataset can take long time):

```
aws s3 sync s3://gdc-target-phs000218-2-open .
```

or

```
aws s3 cp s3://gdc-target-phs000218-2-open . --recursive
```